# Does the noun "propos" match well with the adjective "techniques"?

Tags: usage

In conversation with my friend, I said jokingly:

> C’est reparti pour un tour... Que je ne te reprenne pas à me tenir des **propos** aussi **techniques** !  Quand tu es lancé, tu ne sais plus t'arrêter...

Something about the noun "propos" being coupled with the adjective "techniques" didn't quite sit right with me, though. While I have no qualms about saying "des **mots** **techniques**", I'm not so sure about the phrasing "des **propos techniques**", as opposed to more readily associated adjectives such as "des propos **déplacés** / **personnels** / **insensés** / **méchants**  etc".

Do I need to treat it as a  juxtaposed combination and say the word "techniques" with some intonation, or in the case of writing, for that matter, put it in italics?

> C’est reparti pour un tour... Que je ne te reprenne pas à me tenir des propos aussi ***techniques*** !  Quand tu es lancé, tu ne sais plus t'arrêter...

Comment: Do you have a language blog?

Comment: Sorry, I noticed your questions here and saw you seem pretty passionate about language learning so I was just wondering if you blogged about it or anything like that. Your approach seems unique!

Comment: I sure understand that feeling. Oh well, would have liked to hear about your method. Thanks for replying though!

Comment: Upon second thought, may I ask if there's a way I could ask you a question or two, then? This site doesn't have DMing so it doesn't make it easy and comments don't feel appropriate for it.

Comment: I wish I could. Between my work, personal life, and learning, I'm hard pressed enough as it is to reply to personal mails, IMs and whatnot. So I doubt if I can get around to a response in a timely manner... So... long story short, I'm fortunate enough to be surrounded by multiple languages on a daily basis while living in Japan. I've been working at an international hospital in Japan, as well as having privately made lots of foreign friends both online and in real life in my city, and my current girlfriend is a Russian polyglot with whom I speak in Russian, French, German etc.

Comment: Thanks, if you're pressed for time I won't ask more then. I don't know how anyone could possibly remember that much without it slipping away, though! That's the most impressive part to me. I mean, from all the other languages that you're *not* actively thinking in but have previously studied.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no problem with using the adjective *techniques* with the noun *propos*.

As a side remark, given the formal tone of your sentence, *si* would have been a better choice than *aussi* which is slightly relaxed here although very few people will notice the difference:

> Que je ne te reprenne pas à me tenir des propos si techniques !

Comment: I'm going off at a tangent, but what do you think of the construction: "Que **je** ne te reprenne pas à **nous** tenir des propos si techniques !"?

Comment: That's equally correct, and a better choice if the *propos techniques* were expressed In front of third parties.

Comment: Got it. Again, what do you think of mixing the following two phrases with this "que" construction: "Que je ne te reprenne pas à faire ..., **s'il te plaît !**" or "Que je ne te reprenne pas à faire ..., **c'est compris ?**"?

Comment: *S'il te plaît* is slightly attenuating the sentence tone while *c'est compris* is making it ruder (unless of course this was said a jocular way.)

Comment: I don't recommend using *si* in informal speech. If that was said in a casual context, I think it's better to try and make the rest less formal than to make it even more. I don't *ever* use *si* in casual speech (when it means *aussi*, *tellement*).

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Hey, bro. I used the construction "Que je ne te reprenne pas à faire ..." rather jokingly. Do you think this structure itself is somewhat too high in register?

Comment: I'd say *tenir des propos* is what makes your sentence formal.

Comment: @Alone-zee It's not of high register *per se*, but it's kind of dated. It's something my grandmother would say a lot and my mother would say sometimes. If you said it in a "i'm mimicking old parents" kind of way maybe, but the rest of your sentence implies something more "serious"